# Facebook redirect_url on multiple language site

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

I use wordpress with nice clean urls for example:

1) http://www.mysite.com/fr/concours/

2) http://www.mysite.com/en/contest/

And i link a facebook app to the first url to support my facebook contest on the site for the french portion. But as soon as i try to login on the english portion, it obviously fails, because it is not owned by the app.

This leads me to think i need to create 2 apps handled by the same code, one for the french portion and one of the english portion. Am i right in that line of thought?

What would be your suggestion?

Comment: I really wonder why i'm getting a -1 on this question, this is a perfectly valid discussion topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a single app that points to mysite.com, and create an index action that detects the user's preferred language and redirects accordingly.

Detection may happen according to the browser's `Accept-Language` http header, or the user's locale sent by facebook in the [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter when opening an application.

Comment: I already had this idea but in this weird world i live in, it is not accepted because lots of quebecers have english systems and english browsers but work in french and are offended by the fact that we present them an english site based on their unknown preferences.... starting most of the time with the client owning the site itself... So i have to find a way that will support choosing the language via the url...

Comment: I only talked about autodetection, you'll surely need to provide a way to switch the language. Also: even if someone uses an English system/browser, if their preferred language is French they'll use FB in that language - and FB sends that to you in the linked `signed_request` parameter (you'll need `$data->user->locale`).